# I am getting ANR , when i click on Edittext for texting

Tags: android

I am getting ANR , when i click on Edittext for texting and My logcat giving msg:- Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it.  Outbound queue length: 0.  Wait queue length: 1.)

```
 edit_personal_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit_personal_details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                edit_personal_details_save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                email_et.setFocusable(true);
                website_et.setFocusable(true);
                twitter_id_et.setFocusable(true);
                email_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                website_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                twitter_id_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        email_et.setEnabled(true);
                website_et.setEnabled(true);
                twitter_id_et.setEnabled(true);         
            }
        });

        edit_personal_details_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit_personal_details_save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                edit_personal_details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dob_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                email_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                website_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                twitter_id_et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                email_et.setEnabled(false);
                website_et.setEnabled(false);
                twitter_id_et.setEnabled(false);
                email_et.setFocusable(false);
                website_et.setFocusable(false);
                twitter_id_et.setFocusable(false);
                dob_et_str = dob_et.getText().toString();
                email_et_str = email_et.getText().toString();
                website_et_str = website_et.getText().toString();
                twitter_id_et_str = twitter_id_et.getText().toString();
                AddPersonalDetails addPersonalDetails = new AddPersonalDetails();
                addPersonalDetails.execute();
            }
        });
```

......................AddPersonalDetails Class..................................

```
private class AddPersonalDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String ResponseFromAddPersonalDetails;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Invoke webservice
        profile_sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Userid = profile_sharedPreferences.getString("userId", null);
        WebService wsc = new WebService();
        ResponseFromAddPersonalDetails = wsc.AddPersonalDetails(Userid, dob_et_str, email_et_str, website_et_str, "skype", twitter_id_et_str, serviceToken, "AddPersonalDetails");
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Set response
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Make ProgressBar invisible
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait.......");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

...........................Xml Code............................................

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLinearPersonalDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/social_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Personal Details"
                    android:textColor="@color/profile_name_txt"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit_personal_details_save"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:text="save"
                    android:textColor="@color/layout_profile"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/edit_personal_details"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:background="@color/layout_profile"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/edit_user_name"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/viewbreaker9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/birthday" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Birthday"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dob_et"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/layout_profile"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:text="September 13"
                        android:textColor="@color/profile_name_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#e4e4e4" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/email" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/email_et"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/layout_profile"
                        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="myemail@email.com"
                        android:textColor="@color/profile_name_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#e4e4e4" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_website"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/website" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:text="Website"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/website_et"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/layout_profile"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="www.Iparun.com"
                        android:textColor="@color/profile_name_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#e4e4e4" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_twitter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/twitter" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:text="TWITTER"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_id_et"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/layout_profile"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="ip_arun"
                        android:textColor="@color/profile_name_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Write down AddPersonalDetails Code.

Comment: `when i click on Edittext for texting` Which component is this `Edittext for texting`? It is not in the code posted, only `edit_personal_details` and `edit_personal_details_save` are which are buttons as I understand and not text inputs, but if the ANR happens from another view you should also post the relevant code.

Comment: All code Posted